# New to python trying to learn OOP

Tags: python, list, class, variables

I am new to python and programming. I am working on a script and strugging with how to pass list variables from one class to another. Code is attached. I am not certain how to pass the list from URL class to createRules class.

```
import csv, sys, time
from urlparse import urlparse, urlsplit, urlunsplit


class URL():
    """ Function parses out urls to get needed parts"""

    def processUrl(self):
        fromUrlArr = [[], [], [], []]
        dstUrlArr = [[], [], [], [], []]
        markets = []

        with open('Redirects.csv') as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in readCSV:
                from_url = urlparse(row[0])
                dst_url = urlparse(row[1])
                path = dst_url.path.split('/')[2:]
                dst_path = '/'.join(path)
                market = from_url.path.split('/')[1]
                fromUrlArr[0].append(from_url.scheme) # I want to use the following list in the class below
                dstUrlArr[0].append(dst_url.scheme) 
                fromUrlArr[1].append(from_url.netloc)
                dstUrlArr[1].append(dst_url.netloc)
                fromUrlArr[2].append(from_url.path)
                dstUrlArr[2].append(dst_path)
                fromUrlArr[3].append(from_url.query)
                dstUrlArr[4].append(market)
                dstUrlArr[3].append(dst_url.query)


class Rule():
   def createRules():
       # ticket = str(sys.argv[1])
       # user = str(sys.argv[2])
       # today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting this down. It is a legitimate question

Comment: @Nemo: Probably because it's an off-topic question for this website.

Comment: Nemo, it confuses me as well how my question is off topic on this site. Oh well thanks everyone for your help. Nemo I do have it working now. This has been driving me nuts for a few days. I am a total newb to python. Actually first attempt at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do in general is

```
class A:
    def func(self):
        list1 = ['a']
        list2 = ['b']
        list3 = ['c']
        return list1, list2, list3

class B:
    def newfunc(self):
        func_results = A().func()
        loaded_list1 = func_results[0]
        loaded_list2 = func_results[1]
        loaded_list3 = func_results[2]
```

for your example this would look like:

```
import csv, sys, time
from urlparse import urlparse, urlsplit, urlunsplit

class URL():
    """ Function parses out urls to get needed parts"""
    def processUrl(self):
        with open('Redirects.csv') as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in readCSV:
                from_url = urlparse(row[0])
                dst_url = urlparse(row[1])
                path = dst_url.path.split('/')[2:]
                dst_path = '/'.join(path)
                market = from_url.path.split('/')[1]
                fromUrlArr[0].append(from_url.scheme) # I want to use the following list in the class below
                dstUrlArr[0].append(dst_url.scheme) 
                fromUrlArr[1].append(from_url.netloc)
                dstUrlArr[1].append(dst_url.netloc)
                fromUrlArr[2].append(from_url.path)
                dstUrlArr[2].append(dst_path)
                fromUrlArr[3].append(from_url.query)
                dstUrlArr[4].append(market)
                dstUrlArr[3].append(dst_url.query)
         return fromUrlArr, dstUrlArr, markets

class Rule():
   def createRules(self):
       func_results_to_load = URL().processURL()
       fromUrlArr = func_results_to_load[0]
       dstUrlArr = func_results_to_load[1]
       market = func_results_to_load[2]
       # ticket = str(sys.argv[1])
       # user = str(sys.argv[2])
       # today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       print dstUrlArr[4][2]
```

rule = Rule()
rule.createRules()

Comment: Nemo thanks for the help. I have basically what you put but im not certain how to create the instance . basically at this point I want to print the values of the list from the Rule class. I tried.  rule = RULE()   rule.createRules() but I get TypeError: createRules() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: you need to define createRules with the argument 'self'. Also, if the class is define as Rule(), you need to keep the capitalization consistent. So try rule = Rule() then rule.createRules()

Comment: That gives me      func_results = URL().processURL()
AttributeError: URL instance has no attribute 'processURL'

Comment: can you edit your code above to what it is now? Is your processURL function defined in your URL class a function of self (processURL(self))?

Comment: Nemo, I have it working now. Thanks for your help I am new to site and python. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would pass it as an argument. In Python all object types are passed by reference. So you need to change your definition of `createRules()` a bit. I'm assuming you mean to use it as a factory function and call it on the class, so you need to create a class method.

```
@classmethod
def createRules(cls, myList):
   # do stuff
```

Then you can pass a list to it by calling it like so

```
someList = [1, 2, 3]
rules = Rule.createRules(someList)
```

Comment: In the URL class the list are populated by a file that has a from url and a to url I am parsing out what I need to be able to create apache Rewrite Rules. In the createRules class I am wanting to take those list and process them to generate the Rules. Kinda weird I know but this is my very first attempt at writing OOP I have the script working procedurely. Hope this helps to clarify what I am doing.

Comment: Your usage doesn't change how to pass the lists though. It looks like you have 3 lists, so you'd need to add three arguments. This doesn't really have anything to do with OOP. You need to familiarize yourself with basic function writing.